# Native base 2.10.0: Fresh installation of native base on react-native project gives weird error

Tags: react-native, native-base

So I have spend 2 days trying to install and integrate native-base in a complete new project and the development server is returning response error code of 500.
So basically I created a new project and then start the project. Run successfully. Installed latest version of native-base(2.10). No issue at all. Now as soon as I tried to use a component from it, it throws 500 server error.
Here is the error information:

[image]

This is how my node js terminal looks like and it points to [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968):
[image]

The github issue has lot of suggestions but none of them works for me. It seems like a problem with compatibility of native-base with latest version of react-native. I am on native-base's slack channel and couple of people has similar issues.This is what my package.json looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.0"
  },
```

I am using `windows 10.`
Things I have done to fix the issue:

1. Downgrading React-native to .55
2. Downgrading native base to 2.3
3. Deleting node modules and reinstalling
4. Clearing metro bundle cache
5. Downgarding React to 16.2 verions
6. Creating a new project and starting again from all over

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are having compatibility issues with the current version of react-native you can always create an app with a specific version `react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.57.8`

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your help. Downgrading a solution as well but there are other ways to solve this issue as well. I will post the answer that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update:This issue will be fixed with native-base version of
>   [2.11.0.](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2536#issuecomment-458728188) For now install react-timer-mixin in your project:
>
> > npm install react-timer-mixin

Explanation about issue:
The issue is caused after react native removed `react-timer-mixin` package and seems like native-base is relaying on that package. Here [is the link.](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2536#issuecomment-458728188) of github issue.
So there are 2 ways to solve it for now ( I am not sure if its a proper way to fix it but if you have a better way please suggest):

- Downgrade your react native version. I have found that this versions of react native and native-base work well with each other:

  > ```
  >    "native-base": "^2.8.2",
  >    "react-native": "^0.55.4"
  > ```
- Or install `react-timer-mixin` in your project `npm install react-timer-mixin`. Make sure that you are closing your metro instances and then clearing your cache before running it again. (FYI: I have used this approach)